# Error: [$compile:tpload] Failed to load template

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive

I've got numerous directives in my Angular app, all of which seem to work as expected 95% of the time. Recently I've been running into a problem where on occasion I get a `$compile.tpload` error for one or more directive templates. I haven't had any luck debugging the issue.

This happens both locally and on production, but only occasionally (maybe 5% of the time). Here is an example of one of my directives that has experienced this issue:

```
app.directive('client', ['$http', function($http) {
    return {
        replace: true,
        templateUrl: '/assets/employers/client.html',
        transclude: false,
        scope: {
            result: '=',
            index: '=',
            token: '@'
        }, controller: ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
            // Omitted for brevity
        }]
    }
}]);
```

Here is the HTML for my `client` directive:

```
<div class="clients row" ng-class="index % 2 === 0 ? 'even' : 'odd'">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="results-label left" ng-if="result && result.name"><b>{{result.name}}</b></div>
        <div ng-if="result && result.id" class="btn btn-default pull-right" ng-click="edit()">Edit</div>
        <form ng-show="showEditor" accept-charset="UTF-8" name="companyForm" ng-submit="submit(company);" novalidate>
            <input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓">
            <input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" ng-model="company.token">

            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Company Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" ng-model="company.name" required>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Authorized Users</label>
                <div ng-repeat="i in company.employers_attributes">
                    <div ng-hide="i._destroy" class="row form-group">
                        <div class="col-lg-2">
                            <a ng-click="removeUser($index)" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger">X</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-10">
                            <label>First Name</label>
                            <input class="form-control" ng-model="company.employers_attributes[$index].first_name" />

                            <label>Last Name</label>
                            <input class="form-control" ng-model="company.employers_attributes[$index].last_name" />

                            <label>Email</label>
                            <input class="form-control" ng-model="company.employers_attributes[$index].email" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="btn btn-default" ng-click="addUser()">
                    <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
                    Add User
                </div>
                <input class="btn btn-primary" style="float:right;" name="commit" type="submit" value="Save" ng-disabled="companyForm.$invalid">
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this was a while ago, but did you have any success with this?  We're using Angular 1.3.8 and have been running into the same problem with an app that we run on tablets using the appcache.  We never have any problems on any of the dev machines or other laptops, but the tablets occasionally give us this error.  When one does that we can refresh as often as we want, but it won't work until we stop the chrome process and restart it.  Then the tablet seems to work fine.  Would love to hear if you found a solution!  Thanks

Comment: I didn't sadly. I ended up upgrading to 1.6.x quite awhile ago and haven't seen this problem since. Not sure if that helps you or not.

Comment: Unfortunately not.  But thanks for the reply.  We did finally figure out our specific problem, which had to do with a route with a resolve property that was returning an error.  Thanks!